# If condition passes but it shouldnt pass

Tags: php, laravel

So I am checking couple conditions in if statement:

```
if ($amount !== $payment->price || strtolower($currency) !== strtolower($payment['currency'])) {
    Log::info($amount);
    Log::info($payment->price);
    Log::info(strtolower($currency));
    Log::info(strtolower($payment['currency']));
    $payment->status = Payment::STATUS_NEEDS_ATTENTION;
    $payment->message = Payment::PAYMENT_ERROR;
} else {
    $payment->message = Payment::PAYMENT_ERROR;
    $payment->status = Payment::STATUS_PAID;
}
```

And I don't understand why it passes `if` condition and this is what I get to `Log::info`, as I see it shouldn't pass `if` condition it should go to `else`

```
[2021-09-30 17:23:31] local.INFO: 1397  
[2021-09-30 17:23:31] local.INFO: 1397  
[2021-09-30 17:23:31] local.INFO: eur  
[2021-09-30 17:23:31] local.INFO: eur
```

I don't understand why it meets if condition but not else?

Comment: How can we know if you haven't told us the values of the variables? Please show us the output of `var_dump([$amount, $payment->price, $currency, $payment['currency']]);` Also, you are pulling _price_ from payment as if is an object `$payment->price` but then on the same line pulling _currency_ as if payment is an array `$payment['currency']`. That's a bit odd, no?

Comment: You can try to use the != operator instead of !==

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that the code was logging the values and you output them in your question. However, using `var_dump` should display the data type which may help you understand why `!==` is not the same as `!=`. Also, you still need to address the object Vs. array problem.

Answer (score 1):

The **possible** explanation may lie in `!==` operator that you have used. Their datatype may differ. What you can try is to log their PHP `gettype()` out, or `var_dump()` to check for their datatype.

Why is this w**ould be** the reason? Different package used for payment and carts may return `price` as `string`, different encode format for example.

Furthermore, keep in mind comparing 2 `float` values may not return expected result. Make sure to round them up to the acceptable point, where inaccuracy can be accepted